# Fixing dashed line shake in ParametricPlot

Tags: plotting, animation

[image]

```
Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot[{Sec[t], Tan[t]}, {t, 0, u}, PlotStyle -> Dashed, 
  PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", Exclusions -> All, 
  PlotRange -> 2], {u, 0.001, 2 Pi}]
```

I found that for parametric curves with singularities, using `ParametricPlot` with the dahed line style, there will be shake in some animations, is there a simple way to eliminate shake?

Comment: it is not shaking. This is just illusion.  It is due to the line being drawn each time and the dashes show at different spots on the screen each time.

Comment: @Nasser: Isn't it obvious that OP wants to eliminate exactly this redrawn at different spots? Describing it as shaking has perfect sense to me.

Comment: @azerbajdzan I was just saying it is not actually shaking. But an illusion of shaking due to the dashes being drawn at different places each time. That is all. I do not see what the problem with me saying this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot[{Sec[t], Tan[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  PlotStyle -> Dashed, 
  PerformanceGoal -> "Quality",
  Exclusions -> All, 
  PlotRange -> 2, 
  RegionFunction -> (#3 <= u &)], 
 {u, 0.001, 2 Pi}]
```

[image]

Comment: Hi kglr! I hope you are fine. I used to follow your solutions and was a little worried as you were not around during last months. I have learned a lot from you and hope everything is fine on your side.

Comment: It's nice to know that there is a real sense of community here. I think that, like you @Marteen, I have learned a lot from kglr and other great users, and I always worry when they are absent.

Comment: @Marteen,  thank you so much for the kind words and well wishes. I've had  to take some time off from stack exchange to attend to a few matters back on earth:) Hoping to visit the site more often in a few months.

Comment: @E.Chan-López, thank you so much for your concern and kind words. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 7):

```
pl = ParametricPlot[{Sec[t], Tan[t]}, {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Dashed, Thick, White], 
   PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", Exclusions -> All, PlotRange -> 2];
Manipulate[
 Show[ParametricPlot[{Sec[t], Tan[t]}, {t, 0, u}, 
   PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", Exclusions -> All, PlotRange -> 2], 
  pl], {u, 0.001, 2 Pi}]
```

[image]